# How to merge vertical cells in LaTeX (I want the break should be merged)?

Tags: tables, multirow

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\title{\textbf{IT WORK}}

\author{}

\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.4mm}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{14pt}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\date{\today}

\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}

\hline

\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{RGUKT}\\

\hline

PUC&Boys&1000\\

\cline{2-3}

   &Girls&1000\\
   
\hline

Engineering&Boys&2000\\

\cline{2-3}

           &Girls&2000\\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\vspace{2cm}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{orange!80}}c|c|c|c|c| >{\columncolor{blue!80}}c|c|c|}

\hline

\rowcolor{yellow!80}

\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{PUC-1 Time Table}\\

\hline

\rowcolor{green!70}

\cellcolor{orange!80}

DAY&P1&P2&P3&P4&\cellcolor{blue!100} &P5&P6\\

\hline

MON&P&M&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!30} CLAB}&B&\cellcolor{red!20}IT&C\\

\hline

TUE&C&P&E&M&R&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!30}PLAB}\\

\hline

WED&E&\cellcolor{red!20}IT&P&T&E&C&M\\

\hline

THU&E&T&C&P&A&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{M}\\

\hline

FRI&M&\cellcolor{red!20}IT&E&C&K&P&T\\

\hline

SAT&\cellcolor{red!20}IT&M&T&E& &C&P\\

\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this? (See the two `\multirow` commands)
And maybe you want `|c|` instead of `|l|` in the `\multicolumn`?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\title{\textbf{IT WORK}}

\author{}

\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.4mm}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{14pt}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\date{\today}

\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}

\hline

\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{RGUKT}\\

\hline

\multirow{2}*{PUC}&Boys&1000\\

\cline{2-3}

   &Girls&1000\\
   
\hline

\multirow{2}*{Engineering}&Boys&2000\\

\cline{2-3}

           &Girls&2000\\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\vspace{2cm}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{orange!80}}c|c|c|c|c| >{\columncolor{blue!80}}c|c|c|}

\hline

\rowcolor{yellow!80}

\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{PUC-1 Time Table}\\

\hline

\rowcolor{green!70}

\cellcolor{orange!80}

DAY&P1&P2&P3&P4&\cellcolor{blue!100} &P5&P6\\

\hline

MON&P&M&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!30} CLAB}&B&\cellcolor{red!20}IT&C\\

\hline

TUE&C&P&E&M&R&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!30}PLAB}\\

\hline

WED&E&\cellcolor{red!20}IT&P&T&E&C&M\\

\hline

THU&E&T&C&P&A&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{M}\\

\hline

FRI&M&\cellcolor{red!20}IT&E&C&K&P&T\\

\hline

SAT&\cellcolor{red!20}IT&M&T&E& &C&P\\

\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]